# wcf service reference error

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am adding SVC file as an service reference to the application, then created proxy of it.
When I debug the service reference I am getting the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException was caught   Message=Could not find
>   endpoint element with name 'SoapHttpEndPoint' and contract
>   'SNP.SnpCatalogService' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name
>   could be found in the client element.

written the following code

```
ServiceReference1.SnpCatalogServiceClient obj = new ServiceReference1.SnpCatalogServiceClient();
```

At this point I am getting the above error.

Config section generated by WCF is

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="SoapHttpEndPoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="SoapNetTcpEndPoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
                    transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="svc address"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapHttpEndPoint"
                contract="SnpCatalogService" name="SoapHttpEndPoint" />
            <endpoint address="svc address"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapNetTcpEndPoint"
                contract="SnpCatalogService" name="SoapNetTcpEndPoint" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Post the wcf config section generated by VS.

Comment: Check the SoapHttpEndPoint Contract, in your snippet its SnpCatalogService, but the generated reference is looking for SNP.SnpCatalogService